# Jackson annotation @JsonProperty ignored while serializing to JSON

Tags: maven, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly

### Oberserved Behavior

Our appliation is structed in a pretty complex way, i.e. it consists of three WAR files which get deployed to WildFly 20.0.1.Final.

It contains the following POJO class:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class RequestData {

    @JsonProperty("AccountID")
    protected Long userId;

    @JsonProperty("MessageID")
    protected Long messageId;
}
```

This class gets serialized to a JSON string using Jackson 2. It happens *more or less randomly* that the serialized JSON looks like this:

```json
// actual JSON
{
  "userId": 45,
  "messageId": 18
}

// expected JSON
{
  "AccountID": 45,
  "MessageID": 18
}
```

So it looks as if the `@JsonProperty` annotation is not evaluated properly. Sometimes the request looks fine, often times not.

### What I Have Found Out

From other questions on SO it seems that this might happen in the following cases:

1. Some older Jackson 1.x library is in the classpath.
2. Different versions of Jackson 2.x are in the classpath.

But as far as I can tell, none of this is true. Please see the output of `mvn dependency:resolve` below. I can see neither a Jackson 1.x dependency, nor different versions of Jackson 2.x.

The client is using the "RESTEasy Proxy Framework" as [described here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.1.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#proxies). Maybe there is a correlation?

```java
@Path("api")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface ServiceClient {

    @POST
    List<ResponseData> update(RequestData requestData);
}
```

### Maven Dependency Resolve

```
The following files have been resolved:
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.4:compile
   org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.17.Final:provided
   javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0359:test
   org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.5.Final-redhat-2:provided
   com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.0:provided
   org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:provided
   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.3.17.Final:provided
   javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:provided
   com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:test
   org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
   org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.5:test
   org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
   org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.12.1.Final:compile
   javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
   antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
   net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.3.0:test
   commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
   org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b10:test
   net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.11:provided
   com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:compile
   com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.03:test
   org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:provided
   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
   org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-impl:jar:1.7.2:runtime
   org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
   org.jboss.spec.javax.el:jboss-el-api_3.0_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:provided
   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
   de.uniassist.abis:abis-lib:jar:1.5.0:compile
   org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:provided
   org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:5.3.6.Final:test
   net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:platform:3.3.0:test
   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
   org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
   org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14:test
   com.vaadin:vaadin-cdi:jar:2.0.0:compile
   org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3-b02:provided
   javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
   org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.5.4:test
   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
   org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.5:test
   com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
   org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:provided
   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.4:compile
   com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.13.0:compile
   org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
   org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer:jar:3.12.1.Final:compile
   org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se:jar:2.4.8.Final:test
   org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
   de.uniassist.abis:utility:jar:1.5.0:compile
   junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
   org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14:test
   javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
   com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:test
   org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.4:compile
   org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.5:test
   jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:provided
   org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
   org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
   org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:test
   javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
   org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc:jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.4:compile
   org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14:test
   com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.10:provided
   commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
   jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
   org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
   javax:javaee-api:jar:8.0:provided
   org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.5:test
   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
   org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.20:provided
   org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.5.Final:provided
   org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:jar:1.2.3:test
   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:provided
   com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:provided
   javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:2.0:provided
   org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.2-GA:provided
   org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.3-b02:provided
   stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:test
```

Comment: Try to add the resteasy-jackson2-provider.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha If I understand the RestEasy documentation correctly, then the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` is loaded by default. See this link https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.12.1.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#resteasy_modules_in_wildfly and this one: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.12.1.Final/userguide/html/json.html#d4e1443

Comment: Not sure how it works on the client side. Maybe you need to register the provider. I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but with `mvn dependency:tree` you could check which dependencies are using jackson, in the pom I'm seeing `provided` and this could explain the issue if the client env contains somewhere a jackson library that is loaded as a single dependency or included in another one as transitive.